# не отрабатывает первое условие if

Tags: python, if

почему не работает первый if? Как будто не видит его.. помохите

```
age = int(input("Введите свой возраст: "))
if (age>=112) and (age<=0):
    print("Не може того быты")
elif (age%10==1) and (age != 11) and (age != 111):
   print("Вам",age,"год")
elif (age%10>1) and (age%10<5) and (age!=12) and (age!=13) and (age!=14):
   print("Вам",age,"года")
else:
   print("Вам",age,"лет")
```

Comment: "Не може того быты", чтобы число одновременно было больше 111 и меньше 1:-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вместо *and* оператора в Вашем случае будет корректно использовать оператор *or*.

```
age = int(input("Введите свой возраст: "))
if (age>=112) or (age<=0):
    print("Не може того быты")
```

В вашем случае программа хочет найти возраст больше 111 и меньше 1, а такого быть не может.